# mat-paginator does not show page info

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, paginator

Material paginator does not show page info.

In official documentation, there is **page info**: 'Page 1 of 20' but when I run their own code locally, or in Stackblitz there is different output.

It shows **number of items**: '1-10 of 100'

I am running same version as documentation

Is this **bug**, or did I **messed up** some property setup?

See images:

mat docu:
[image]

stackblitz:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a property called **getRangeLabel** available for MatPaginator. You can use it to change the label as you want.

In your component, set up your paginator:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static : false}) paginator!: MatPaginator;
```

Then assign a custom function in the afterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Your custom text';
 }
```

------------------------ **OR** ------------------------

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getRangeDisplayText;
  }
```

Then set up a custom function to display the text you need:

```
getRangeDisplayText = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
  const initialText = `Displaying users`;  // customize this line
  if (length == 0 || pageSize == 0) {
    return `${initialText} 0 of ${length}`;
  }
  length = Math.max(length, 0);
  const startIndex = page * pageSize;
  const endIndex = startIndex < length 
    ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) 
    : startIndex + pageSize;
  return `${initialText} ${startIndex + 1} to ${endIndex} of ${length}`; // customize this line
};
```

This will use whatever pageSize and length you have in your HTML or have configured in your component.

```
<mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.total"
      [pageSize]="10"
      hidePageSize
      showFirstLastButtons>
```

If your data returns 50 records, this will show this text:

***Displaying users 1 to 10 of 50***

Answer (score 1):

one possible fix that I came up with is add custom element

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {  
    // get mat sub component
    const list = this.customPagingItems.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-range-actions");
    if (!!list[0]) {    
      // add page info element
      const div = this.renderer.createElement("div");
      this.renderer.addClass(div, "mat-paginator-page-info");
      list[0].appendChild(div);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // update page info because mat-paginator is missing that
    const list = this.customPagingItems.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("mat-paginator-page-info");
    if (!!list[0]) list[0].innerHTML = `Page ${this.currentPage.toString()} of ${this.totalPages.toString()}`;
  }
```

order of elements is done in CSS by adding `order` property since it is display:flex (no need of directive overkill)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the 'getRangeDisplayText' method globally. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class PaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
        super();
    }

    public getRangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
        return `${this.translateService.translate('Page')} ${page + 1} ${this.translateService.translate('of')} ${Math.ceil(length / pageSize)}`;
    };
}
```

and provide it in AppModule (or another one):

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: PaginatorIntl },
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also, you can provide it in unique components, if this change is not required globally:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-table',
    templateUrl: './table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: PaginatorIntl },
    ],
})
export class TableComponent {}
```